# Set item in action bar on left

Tags: android

This is my code in main_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:title="@string/action_add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

</menu>
```

And I want set this item to left of action bar. Thank for every answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom layout and set in the actionBar in following way in 
onCreate method of activity

```
ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
mActionBar.setCustomView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_view, null));
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```